# I want to optimize the query-sql

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

since there is a lot of data in the database, the query does not work, I need to compare values from one layer with another, find those values from the new layer that are not in the old one.

**THIS IS MY QUERY:**

```sql
select distinct id_gs,nmbr_tusa
from "NEW_SLOY"."SHILPU"
where date_contract  >= '2023-05-01'
and id_gs not in(select id_gs from "OLD_SLOY"."SHILPU")
```

Comment: You say your query "does not work". Please be more specific. Does it return incorrect results, run too slowly, or what? To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this statement? And share the DDL for the table and indexes involved? (please, everything in plain text, not images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subquery, you can use `left join`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.id_gs, N.nmbr_tusa
FROM "NEW_SLOY"."SHILPU" N
LEFT JOIN "OLD_SLOY"."SHILPU" O
ON N.id_gs = O.id_gs
WHERE N.date_contract >= '2023-05-01'
AND O.id_gs IS NULL;
```

When you have a lot of rows in a subquery. It compares every row in a main query with every row in a subquery. It leads to a huge number of comparisons.

you can read more about `left join` here:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-left-join/

Comment: @Felipe Felix does it make sence?